# Is there a generalization of Wick's Theorem *(or Isserlis' theorem) to non-random, rectangular matrices.

Tags: statistics, multivariate-statistical-analysis

Say we have several rectangular matrices (J,K) of different shapes, and we want to evaluate the Expected value, or Trace, of their Product

$$
\mathbb{E}[J_{1}^{T}J_{2}^{T}J_{3}^{T}K_{3}K_{2}K_{1}]
$$

where by the expected value here  I mean the gaussian integral
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{M}]=\int d^{n}x e^{\frac{-1}{2}\mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{Mx}}
$$

Where the matrices are real but rectangular, and of different shapes, and non-random

i.e  say the dimensions of the matrices are

$$J_{3}, K_{3}\;are\;(1000\times300), $$
$$J_{2}, K_{2}\;are\;(300\times100), $$
$$J_{1}, K_{1}\;are\;(100\times10)$$

Is there a way to express this using a Generalization of Wick's theorem (or Isserlis' theorem), to give something like

$$
\mathbb{E}[J_{1}^{T}K_{1}]\times\mathbb{E}[J_{2}^{T}K_{2}]\times\mathbb{E}[J_{3}^{T}K_{3}]+\cdots
$$

Comment: You said the "matrices are real but of different shapes, and non-random." Do you mean that the shapes are non-random, as one would anticipate? Or do you mean that the matrices are non-random? If the matrices are non-random, then what do you mean by the expectation symbol $\mathbb{E}$?

Comment: Please see my edits above, thank you